# random_int instead of array_rand in a loop with no doubles

Tags: php, random

I'm trying to create a generator for a lotto that I play very often.
The lotto is a **5 number draw**, ranging from **number 1-50** and **the same number cannot appear again**.

My current approach to do this is using `array_rand()` but after some reading I noticed that I should not use `array_rand()` for this purpose, instead I should be using `random_int()`.

My current approach below:

```
$numbers = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50);
 for ($i = 0; $i <= 4; $i++) {
    $number = array_rand($numbers);
    unset($numbers[$number]);
 if ($number == 0) {
    $number = array_rand($numbers);
    unset($numbers[$number]);
 }
    $out1[] = array("<div class=\"number\">$number</div>");
 }
```

As you can see above, this works and it generates 5 numbers without duplicating because I unset the number after it's been drawn.

**My question is:**

**How can I do the same as above but using `random_int()`instead?**


*To clarify: Use `random_int()` to generate a random number but ensure that it doesnt generate the same number again in that run.*

Comment: shuffle() and the first 5 keys, there are other options

Comment: `shuffle()` is not random enough. http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php

Comment: `$numbers = range(1,50);`

Comment: I think array_rand is the best choice for your scenario but please replace array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7..., 50) with range(1, 50)

Comment: for a game? says who? @JonasJohansson

Comment: I can't replace 1,2,3,4,5 with range(1, 50) because then I wouldn't be able to unset that number.

Comment: php.net. They link to random_int and suggest you to use that instead for my purpose. To quote php.net:
_Generates cryptographic random integers that are suitable for use where unbiased results are critical, such as when shuffling a deck of cards for a poker game._

Comment: Good point! Everyone knows all online games are made to make you loose anyway so why bother with this small detail.

Comment: @Andreas I did, and as I suspected it allowed me to generate the same number twice :)

Comment: Bull*. Range create an array just like your goofy code does

Comment: @nogad I'm not running a real lottery no. I am how ever providing a generator that is to be used with a real lottery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the way:

```
$out = [];
$used = [];
for ($i = 0; $i <= 4; $i++) {
  do {
    $randInt = random_int(1, 50);
  } while (in_array($randInt, $used));
  $used[] = $randInt;
  $out[] = "<div class=\"number\">$randInt</div>";
}
```

Comment: @JonasJohansson  make sure that you try to run this solution multiple time. This will also produce duplicates at some point of time. And you din't answer my comments. My code is flawless BTW

Comment: @AlivetoDie How would this produce duplicates?

Answer (score 1):

```
$numbers = array();   // Create an empty array
while (count($numbers) < 5) {   // While less than 5 items in the array repeat the following
    $random = random_int(1,50);   // Generate a random number
    if (!in_array($random, $numbers)) {   // Check if the random number is already in the array, and if it is not then:
        $numbers[] = $random;  // add the random number to the array
    }
}
    foreach ($numbers as $n) {   // Loop over your array and output with your added HTML
  echo "<div class=\"number\">$n</div>";
}
```